# Adding double quotes in a string with AND and OR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to generate this **output**:

```
"word1" AND "word2" OR "word3 word4"
```

from this **input** string:

```
word1 AND word2 OR word3 word4
```

what I have so far:

```
DECLARE

@string  NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @string = 'word1 , word2 | word3 word4'
SET @string = REPLACE(REPLACE( @string , ',' , ' AND ' ), '|' , ' OR ' )
SELECT QUOTENAME(@string,'"')
```

what are the possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a very odd request.  The following SQL will do this:

```
select '"'+replace(replace(col, ' AND ', '" AND "'), ' OR ', '" OR "')+'"'
from (select 'word1 AND word2 OR word3 word4' as col) t;
```

You can do it without a subquery as well:

```
set @string = '"'+replace(replace(@string, ' AND ', '" AND "'), ' OR ', '" OR "')+'"';
```